# Cambiar de color a un TexView según el valor del digito en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, textview, paso-por-valor

Hola a todos aun ando en esto queriendo aprender llevo mas de 2 semanas sin encontrar el resultado de este problema con la pena de resolverlo con ustedes. (deberia de saber como plantearlo) unicamente lo encontre con php, lo ando tratando de hacer en java.

Ejemplo:
Tengo un textview que cuando asigno el digito me aparece de un color, quiero que detecte el color segun su valor es decir si pongo 500 lo detecte de color verde, si esta en 250 se ponga de color amarillo y si esta en 100 se ponga de color rojo,

Otro ejemplo: 10 se asigna el verde y ya bajando a 5 se vuelve amarilo y llegando casi a 0 llegue a rojo?

rescate esto de otra pregunta dentro de la comunidad.

```
 if(!auxValor.isEmpty() && auxValor.equals("500")){
textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verde));
}
```

Aqui se aprecia que se signo el digito 500 de lo cual lo viene reflejando con el color verde, algo asi quiero realizar en java.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar se los agradeceria.

ACTUALIZACION:

```
    public void onClick(View view) {

    String n1 = ocrResultView.getText().toString();
    String n2 = tv1.getText().toString();

    int entero1 =Integer.parseInt(n1);
    int entero2 =Integer.parseInt(n2);

    int rta=0;

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_resta:
            if(entero1 >= entero2 ){
                rta = 0; //Si entero1 (ocrResultView) es mayor, siempre darìa 0.
            }else {
                rta = entero1 - entero2;
                rta = Math.abs(rta); 
            }
            break;
    }
    tv1.setText(""+rta);

    TextView resultado = tv1; 

    if(resultado < 1){

        tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    }else if(resultado >= 1 && resultado < 7){

        tv1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

    }else if(resultado >= 7 && resultado <=10){

        tv1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente es cuestión de agregar los otros dos condicionamientos, pero te recomendaría mejor usar un Switch :

```
 monto = 500;
    
    switch(monto){
        case 500: 
            textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.verde));
            break;
        case 250: 
            textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.amarillo));
            break;
        case 100: 
            textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rojo));
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo está bien, pero no puedes asignarle un valor fijo a monto porque sino nunca saldrá del primer case.

Comment: Aah por supuesto, solamente lo ponía como ejemplo. Tambíen note que el tenia otra expresión dentro de su condicíon la cual verifica si el valor esta vacío, y en este caso podríamos usar el default para también colocar el color verde.

Comment: Agradecido ando muchas gracias por sus aportaciones se verefica de un solo digito, en si como puedo detectar mediante el digito que cambie de color a que llegue a 0? ejemplo 10 se asigna el verde y ya bajando a 5 se vuelve amarilo y llegando casi a 0 llegue a rojo?

Comment: Pues para eso si vas a necesitar un if, y lo único que debes hacer es cambiar el == por un <=, editó mi respuesta para que entiendas

Answer (score 0):

Pues, la solución es igual a lo que muestras que encontraste. Suponiendo que tienes una variable llamada **RESULTADO** de tipo `INT` pues haces un `if` y según el resultado cambias el color del texto. Por ejemplo:

```
        int resultado = valorA + valorB; //esto es un ejemplo simple

        if(resultado == 100){
            tvEjemplo.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }else if(resultado == 250){
            tvEjemplo.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }else if(resultado == 500){
            tvEjemplo.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Si lo que deseas es que sea entre un rango comprendido, sólo debes hacer uso del if y el and. Supongamos que quieres que los números entre 7 y 10 sean verdes, entre 1 y 6 sean amarillos y los menores a 1 en rojo:

```
        int resultado = valorA + valorB; //esto es un ejemplo simple

        if(resultado < 1){
            tvEjemplo.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }else if(resultado >= 1 && resultado < 7){
            tvEjemplo.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }else if(resultado >= 7 && resultado <=10){
            tvEjemplo.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2:**

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(ocrResultView.getText().toString());
    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString());

    int rta=0;

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btn_resta:
            if(n1 >= n2 ){
                rta = 0; //Si entero1 (ocrResultView) es mayor, siempre darìa 0.
            }else {
                rta = n1 - n2;
                rta = Math.abs(rta); 
            }
            break;
    }

    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(rta))

    if(rta < 1){
        
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    }else if(rta >= 1 && rta < 7){

        tv1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

    }else if(rta >= 7 && rta <=10){

        tv1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muy interesante, Otro ejemplo: 10 se asigna el verde y ya bajando a 5 se vuelve amarilo y llegando casi a 0 llegue a rojo? como se podria hacer como tipo rainbow cada vez que se asigne el precio se refleje el color? saludos!

Comment: Ando implementando el codigo pero me marcar error en el .setTextColor. ando toda la tarde/noche tratando de resolverlo pero no me da resultado tendras algun link donde me pueda guiar, te lo agradeceria.

Comment: Hola franqo en si ya lo resolvi nomas que me quedo con una pequeña duda int resultado = valorA + valorB; en si que es? de poner el valor 0 a 10? o asignarlo con textview correspondiente, soy nuevo disculpa mi torpes.

Comment: Hola Franqo aun ando con esto si buscando, no le hayo la solucion ando desde la mañana ahorita ya noche, arriba actualize con el codigo completo espero que me puedas ayudar te lo agradeceria,

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta @MenchacaMoto